# hacer que elimine mi funcion con la mismo boton

Tags: javascript

hola quiero saber como puedo hacer que elimine este codigo tambien, la pagina html tiene un boton que crea, y al volver presionar elimina el nodo que fue creado. Realmente no sé como realizarlo

```
function puchar() 
{
    var nuevaimagen = document.createElement("img");
    // nuevaimagen.setAttribute("src","img/gato.png");
    nuevaimagen.src = "img/gato.jpg";
    var div = document.getElementById("imagen");
    div.appendChild(nuevaimagen);

}
```

Comment: está pregunta está fuera de contexto, no se entiende lo que preguntas

Comment: Que quieres hacer realmente??? cuando te refieres a que quieres que elimine. Sera que quieres vaciar el div antes de agregar la nueva imagen. Se un poco mas claro para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: la pagina html tiene un boton que crea, y al volver presionar elimina el nodo que fue creado. Realmente no sé como realizarlo.

Comment: **No** pongas información relevante **en los comentarios**. En lugar de ello, pulsa en [edit] tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// creamos la funcion puchar
function puchar(e){
// guardamos el elemento clickeado
let btn = e.target;
//seleccionamos le id imagen
let div = document.getElementById("imagen");
// validamos que existe un hijo para imagen
if(div.children[0]){
    //si existe un hijo lo eliminamos
    div.removeChild(div.children[0]);
    // cambia el texto al boton
    btn.innerText = "Crear";
    // paramos la ejecucion haciendo un return;
    return;
}

// si no existe hijo continua aqui
// cambia el texto al boton
btn.innerText = "Eliminar";
//crea el elemento imagen
let nuevaimagen = document.createElement("img");
// agrega a el elemento creado un attributo src con su url
nuevaimagen.src = "https://static2.lasprovincias.es/www/multimedia/201706/25/media/cortadas/gato-kngE-U4015529328506D-624x385@Las%20Provincias.jpg";
// agrega el elemento a div con id imagen
div.appendChild(nuevaimagen);
}

// seleccionamos el button y esperamos que alla un evento click para llamar a la funcion puchar
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click",puchar);
```

```html
<button id="button">Crear</button>
</br></br>
<div id="imagen"></div>
```